# Spring Mono ZIP using args as argument

Tags: spring

Anything wrong with the below code, the lambda function is not executing. How to use the args ? Any help would be appreciated. The lambda function is not executing

```
Mono<String> test = Mono.just("test");
   Mono<String> testtwo = Mono.just("testTwo");
   Mono<String> str = Mono.zip(args -> {
        return (String) args[0];
    });
    System.out.println(str); // This is printing MonoEmpty
```